# Multi-field search with searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

My code to search multi-able with searchkick fields doesn't seem to work

```
search = params[:term].present? ? params[:term] : nil

combos = if search
  Combo.search(search, fields: [:game_name, :character_name])
else
  Combo.all.page(params[:page])
end
```

I get a

F, [2018-05-11T05:11:29.348920 #4] FATAL -- : [2879ef07-9eae-43e2-9c89-9e7a55aac2ae] NoMethodError (undefined method `joins' for #):

in my heroku log. I feel like this is a quick fix but i'm stumped.

**edit added log and gemfile**

```
2018-05-11T06:09:08.074664+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=combobook.net request_id=6ef470c5-6df6-46ca-b73c-8e6e1bf9a6e3 fwd="72.83.52.163,172.68.65.219" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=36ms status=200 bytes=6168 protocol=https
2018-05-11T06:09:55.502333+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/combos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=r&button=" host=combobook.net request_id=107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed fwd="72.83.52.163,172.68.65.217" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=59ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2018-05-11T06:09:55.443112+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.442916 #4]  INFO -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed] Started GET "/combos?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=r&button=" for 172.68.65.217 at 2018-05-11 06:09:55 +0000
2018-05-11T06:09:55.445117+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.445002 #4]  INFO -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed] Processing by CombosController#index as HTML
2018-05-11T06:09:55.445293+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.445162 #4]  INFO -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "term"=>"r", "button"=>""}
2018-05-11T06:09:55.488673+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.488519 #4] DEBUG -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed]   [1m[33mCombo Search (40.2ms)[0m  curl https://spruce-6383279.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443/combos_production/_search?pretty -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"size":10000,"from":0,"query":{"dis_max":{"queries":[{"match":{"game_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"game_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"game_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}},{"match":{"game_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}},{"match":{"character_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search"}}},{"match":{"character_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":10,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2"}}},{"match":{"character_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}},{"match":{"character_name.analyzed":{"query":"r","boost":1,"operator":"and","analyzer":"searchkick_search2","fuzziness":1,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":3,"fuzzy_transpositions":true}}}]}},"timeout":"11s","_source":false}'
2018-05-11T06:09:55.497046+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.496903 #4]  INFO -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms (Searchkick: 40.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-05-11T06:09:55.498165+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.498095 #4] FATAL -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed]   
2018-05-11T06:09:55.498556+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2018-05-11T06:09:55.498491 #4] FATAL -- : [107260a0-8790-4e4e-b435-ec7ee557b5ed] NoMethodError (undefined method `joins' for #<Searchkick::Results:0x00000005165940>):
```

---

```
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'cocoon'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'seed_dump'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem "rails-erd"
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

---

added relavent controller info

```
  def sort_and_paginate_combos(combos)
    combos.joins(:stars)
          .group(:id)
          .order('COUNT(stars.id) DESC')
          .page(params[:page])
  end
```

Comment: undefined method `joins` for what exactly? I'm sure this information is in log. And where does this error point to in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey As I can check if the search term is absence it fetches Active Record results instead of Serachkiq results.

Follwoing code you can try

```
search = params[:term].present? ? params[:term] : '*'

combos = Combo.search(search, fields: [:game_name, :character_name], page: params[:page])
```

Hope it works for more detail please provide detail about `combos` iteration.

Comment: I made the changes to Combo.search, but still get the same error.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about at which line you get this error?

Comment: I added the controller action, It looks like an active record issue.

Comment: Yup joins methods not available for Searckick results relation.To joins a relation you can follow this  [link](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/700)

Comment: And for others functionalities please have a look the provided documentation [link](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick)